# How to use var name

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables named grandFather.  My function is to find if grandFather is alone and give his grand children some cakes ...

**Problem:**
There is something wrong with `var giftOne`

Please give me a hand.  Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  var lonelyGrandDad = ".grandFather";
  if ($(lonelyGrandDad).has('.alone')) {
    var giftOne = $(lonelyGrandDad + ' .father table');
    giftOne.find(".firstChild").append(" Cake");
    giftOne.find(".secondChild").append(" pan Cake");
    giftOne.find(".thirdChild").append(" Donut");
  }
})
```

```css
tr {
  display: grid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandFather alone">
  <div class="father">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstChild">first Child</td>
        <td class="secondChild">second Child</td>
        <td class="thirdChild">third Child</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandFather">
  <div class="father">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstChild">first Child</td>
        <td class="secondChild">second Child</td>
        <td class="thirdChild">third Child</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot the `+` character to concatenate the strings. Always check the console when you have an issue with JS as this syntax error will appear in there. I'm voting to close this question as it's caused by a typo.

Comment: Fixed the snippet by adding jQuery and the missing +. Please delete the question

Comment: Sorry, If I add a +, it still not working as expect!  The request is to give a cake, pancake and donut to grandFather has class `.alone'

Comment: In this case you need to loop over all the `.grandfather` elements and evaluate them individually. I've added an answer for you below.

Comment: The problem is with `.has('.alone')` - it returns a new jquery object, not a bool.  Also worth reviewing [has](https://api.jquery.com/has/) which states *Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector* - so it's (probably) the equivalent of `$(".grandFather").find(".alone").closest(".grandFather")`.  You *probably* wanted `$(".grandfather").is(".alone")`

Comment: **note:** some of the answers (downvoted/deleted ones) were added *before* the typo was fixed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your explanation of the goal in the comments under the question:

> The request is to give a cake, pancake and donut to grandFather has class `.alone'

You need to loop through the `.grandFather` elements and evaluate them individually. You can use `filter()` before the loop to retrieve only those which also have the `.alone` class - assuming you cannot just amend the `lonelyGrandDad` string to be `.grandFather.alone`.

From there you can use the `this` keyword in the loop to reference the element in the iteration and find it's relevant children by class before appending content to them.

Note that your original use of `has()` was flawed as it looks for child elements to the target, not the target itself.

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var lonelyGrandDad = ".grandFather";
  
  $(lonelyGrandDad).filter('.alone').each(function() {
    let $grandDad = $(this);
    $grandDad.find(".firstChild").append(" Cake");
    $grandDad.find(".secondChild").append(" pan Cake");
    $grandDad.find(".thirdChild").append(" Donut");    
  }); 
})
```

```css
tr {
  display: grid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandFather alone">
  <div class="father">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstChild">first Child</td>
        <td class="secondChild">second Child</td>
        <td class="thirdChild">third Child</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandFather">
  <div class="father">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstChild">first Child</td>
        <td class="secondChild">second Child</td>
        <td class="thirdChild">third Child</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rory McCrossan, Thank you very much for giving a hand! and it is greatly appreciated for your clearly explanation!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

I changed the selector class of the lonelyGrandDad. The selector `.grandFather.alone` will give you all the lonely grandfathers. Note that there is **no space** between the classes. This tells the selector that both conditions `.grandfather`  and `.alone` should apply.

Those selector are the same as CSS selectors.

```js
$(function() {
  var lonelyGrandDad = ".grandFather.alone";
  var giftOne = $(lonelyGrandDad + ' .father table');
  giftOne.find(".firstChild").append(" Cake");
  giftOne.find(".secondChild").append(" pan Cake");
  giftOne.find(".thirdChild").append(" Donut");
})
```

```css
tr {
  display: grid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandFather alone">
  <div class="father">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstChild">first Child</td>
        <td class="secondChild">second Child</td>
        <td class="thirdChild">third Child</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandFather">
  <div class="father">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstChild">first Child</td>
        <td class="secondChild">second Child</td>
        <td class="thirdChild">third Child</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi basti500, Thank you very much for your help!  I have learned a short way from your code, greatly appreciated!